# How to add conio.h into nvcc in linux

Tags: c++, c, header, nvcc

i'm a new devopler in CUDA 8 and compiling my codes with nvcc
how can i install conio.h into my compiler 
by the way i'm running my code on server at a company
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: you can't.
CUDA is based on C, but is a different language and a different compiler. And conio.h is not even part of C standard.
You ca however use printf from a Cuda kernel